# What is a pickup table?

Tags: sql, database

I'm developing a small application using the Clarizen API. The documentation references "pickup tables" numerous times, but the description

> "Pick up tables are similar to the Regular entity types. Pick up tables usually contain limited set of fields and limited number of entities and are referenced from the other types of classes."

is meaningless to me. I've been trying to figure out what a pickup table is from context, but I'm stuck there too.

Some example fields from the documentation:

> Country | Entity | Represents country. | Reference to the pickup table “Countries”.
>
> State | Entity | Represents lifecycle State of the entity. For example, possible states of the Work Itemobjects can be Draft, Active, Cancelled, Completed, On Hold. Value is a reference to Statepickup table.

These examples make me think it's just a static list (which doesn't fit their given definition of pick up table), but if so the list/table is not provided to the user so I'm not sure how I would make use of it. If it does in fact refer to a static list, I'm going to have to try to coax them into giving me the tables.

I can't find a definition of pickup table online, so if anyone here knows it would help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's another name for a junction table, or association table. There are only foreign keys that refer to primary keys in other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Pickup tables are picklists. The values of the picklist are stored in mini-tables (not really sure why but doesn't seem to be that important).

The work item state example is an example of a picklist.